# How to make props equal to state that does not exist yet?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Solved Thank you for your help**

I am setting props of component

```
<Component myprops={state_variable}/>
```

The problem is that when I am creating the component and setting the props the state variable does not exist yet and my code breaks. What can I do to solve this problem? In addition when I change the state the prop is not updated.

```
 <ServiceTicket 
  
  showOverlay={Tickets_disabled_withError[ticket_num]?.isDisabled}
  showSelectedError={Tickets_disabled_withError[ticket_num]?.showError}

  />
```

My intial state initial variable:

```
 const [Tickets_disabled_withError,setTickets_disabled_withError] = useState({})
```

I am trying to call function that will update state and change value that props is equal to.

```
const OverLayOnAll = (enable) =>
{

  let tempobject =  Tickets_disabled_withError
  
  for (let key in tempobject)
  {
     if (enable == "true")
     {
      tempobject[key].isDisabled = true
     }
     else if (enable == "false")
     {
        tempobject[key].isDisabled = false
     }
    
  }

  setTickets_disabled_withError(tempobject)

}
```

I fixed the issue. Thank you so much for your help. I had to set use optional chaining ?. and also re render the component.

Comment: Do you use Class component?

Comment: No I am using functional component

Comment: So, what do you mean by the state variable?

Comment: You need to rewrite your code such that it will *not* break when props are empty.  Usually this boils down to checking whether each variable exists before trying to use it. Optional chaining (`foo?.bar`) is also frequently helpful.   For more specific answers you'll need to include some code in your question.

Comment: Do you mean, you want to set a prop as an initial value for one of your state variables?

Comment: No I am trying to set props to const[statevariable, setstatevariable] = useState()

Comment: It's impossible for your state variable to not exist. In your example, you have it as snake case, but you defined your `useState` variable as `statevariable`

Comment: My state variable is an object and at the time that I am setting it the object key does not exist. It is undefined at the same that I am setting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value exists. It's just that the value itself is `undefined`. You need to set an initial value when defining your state

```js
const [statevariable, setstatevariable] = useState({
  somekey: {
    isDisabled: false // or whatever the initial value should be
  }
}) // or whatever else you need it to be
```

For your second problem, you are using the same pointer. JavaScript does equality by reference. You've transformed the existing value, so React doesn't detect a change. The easiest way to fix this is to create a shallow copy before you start transforming

```js
let tempobject =  {...Tickets_disabled_withError}
```

Comment: The prop will be equal to something like statevariable.somekey.isDisabled
which is not there when setting the prop.

Comment: Do a simple check first and use a default value in that case.

Comment: It  is not updating the prop value when I change the state.

Comment: @JoeySmith Updated. I made it an empty object because I didn't know what the content was. Just change the initial value to whatever you need it to be

Comment: I added some more code to explain my issue some more.

Comment: It still does not work. The state is updating but the new update is not reflected in prop value. The prop value says undefined.

Comment: The issue is when I set the value of the prop that value does not exist yet. I am also setting with key of an object with a variable

Comment: @Andrew I solved the issue. I had to re render the components like you described. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear to me, but there's a problem in your `setTickets_disabled_withError` call.
When you update a state property (`ticketsDisabledWithError`) using its previous value, you need to use the callback argument.
(See https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

```
overlayAll = (enable)=> {
    setTicketsDisabledWithError((ticketsDisabledWithError)=> {
        return Object.keys(ticketsDisabledWithError).reduce((acc,key)=> {
            acc[key].isDisabled = (enabled=="true");
            return acc;
        }, {}); // initial value of reduce acc is empty object
    })
}
```

Also, please learn JS [variable naming conventions](https://www.robinwieruch.de/javascript-naming-conventions/). It'll help both you, and those who try to help you.